# Make Google Maps content relative to the right instead of the left

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps on a site and when I increase the size of my map's div the content doesn't move with respect to the top and the left (which is fully reasonable in most cases) and new content is shown on the right and the bottom. I'd like to flip this behaviour horizontally, so that when I resize it the content doesn't move with respect to the top and the right and the new content is shown on the left instead. Is this possible?

The size of the map div is going to get resized with animations and when the window is resized so it has to be a smooth solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try re-centering the map using `setCenter()` on resize. You might want to debounce the function that centers it though.

### Edit

Here's an actual example on the API docs. [EventListeners](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventListeners)

Comment: This is the approach I would take, but to do it correctly there would be some math involved in calculating what the new center should be.

Comment: Actually you don't. I've linked to the example in the api.

Comment: That example will maintain the same center point, but the OP requested that new content fill in on the left side of the viewport. In that case you must calculate the size difference of the viewport and what LatLng offset the new center point should be at the current zoom level. Doable, but not trivial either. It also wouldn't be a smooth transistion.

Comment: Yeah but I think he's actually looking to keep the map in view and doesn't know you can reset the centre point. "the content doesn't move with respect to the top and the left (which is fully reasonable in most cases)" I could be wrong though. To make it smoother just reduce the delay in `setTimeout()`.