# Anchoring a google map to right side of its container

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've noticed that the google maps API (and google maps in general) always anchors maps to the left-hand side of their container, like [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple) (resize the window).

I have a situation where I'd like the map to be anchored to the right hand side. I can't find anything in the API docs referring to this. Is it possible?

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979560/make-google-maps-content-relative-to-the-right-instead-of-the-left) suggests re-rendering the map with an event listener on resize but this isn't preferable as I'm looking for the effect of a sidebar panel sliding in and 'over top' the map rather than pushing it to the side and then having the map re-center itself afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an Event listener on the ['resize' or 'bounds_changed'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) event?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'resize', function(event) {
    map.setCenter(myLocation); // 
});
```

This should center the map smoothly as the containing div is resized.

Notes:

- You might have to create the resize [event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event) manually.
- 'map' is a Map type object from the Google API
- 'MyLocation' is a LatLng object

`var myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.679216211612086,151.3031796875);`

Comment: `bounds_changed` seems to be the appropriate event but I'm not finding any documentation about a myLocation object?

Comment: the `myLocation` object I referenced above is a `LatLng` type object eg `var myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.679216211612086,151.3031796875);`